# How can we perform "Prefix Matching" in Redisearch over numbers?

Tags: redis, redisearch

I have a field **marks**. It is a numeric field so, as per Redis, we should perform search something like this:

```
@marks:[10 5000]
```

**or**

```
@marks:[10 inf]
```

But I want functionality as above and in addition with functionality as below

```
@marks:10*
```

So, I will get set of marks something like this:
{101, 102,..., 1011, 1012, 1021, 1022,..., 10011,...}

Is it possible in Redisearch as I could not find any way to perform @marks:10* on numeric fields

Answer (score 1):

You can index the same field with two different alias names e.g.

```
FT.CREATE myidx ON HASH PREFIX 1 doc: SCHEMA marks as marks-txt TEXT name as marks-num NUMERIC
```

Then you can do both:

```
@marks-num:[10 5000]
```

And

```
@marks-txt:10*
```

Comment: Thanks @Guy for replying. Don't you think that it will increase memory consumption? If we have 1000 integer fields then we are going to make them double i.e. 2K fields.

Comment: It might increase the memory since you need to index twice in two modes, but it won't duplicate the data in Redis key space since it's just an alias to the same field.